# Lodash update element values from another array Chain / Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

How I can update an array element values with another array elements data values, using **Lodash**

```
var Master_Array [
{ Name: "Jon", Region: "North America & Caribbean" },
{ Name: "Ruan", Region: "Asia Pacific" }
]

var Regions_Map = [
{ Region: 'Europe', NewRegion: 'EMEA' },
{ Region: 'North America & Caribbean', NewRegion: 'NAC' },
{ Region: 'Asia Pacific', NewRegion: 'APAC' }
]
```

I think that can be did with:

```
_.chain()
.mapValues( ...blá blá... )
.values()
.value();
```

Expected result:

```
var Master_Array [
{ Name: "Jon", Region: "NAC" },
{ Name: "Ruan", Region: "APAC" }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to execute `mapValues` as you are iterating a collection and not an object, `mapKeys` and `mapValues` is preferable iterating objects and mapped to another

Now, approach 1, if you want to run something that will return a new array of your expected items then try with `map` like this

```
var EXPECTED_RESULT = _.map(Master_Array, function(item){
    var newItem = {};
    newItem.Name = item.Name;
    newItem.Region = _.find(Regions_Map, {Region: item.Region}).NewRegion
    return newItem;
});
```

and if you want to modify the existing array, then just loop over it either by loadash or normal javascript loop, and perform the operation

```
_.each(Master_Array,function(item){
    item.Region = _.find(Regions_Map, {Region: item.Region}).NewRegion
} )
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `map` and `find`:

```js
var Master_Array = [
{ Name: "Jon", Region: "North America & Caribbean" },
{ Name: "Ruan", Region: "Asia Pacific" }
];

var Regions_Map = [
{ Region: 'Europe', NewRegion: 'EMEA' },
{ Region: 'North America & Caribbean', NewRegion: 'NAC' },
{ Region: 'Asia Pacific', NewRegion: 'APAC' }
];

Master_Array = Master_Array.map((person) => ({
  Name: person.Name,
  Region: Regions_Map.find((region) => region.Region === person.Region).NewRegion
}));

console.log(Master_Array);
```

Answer (score 0):

A javascript solution

```js
var Master_Array = [
{ Name: "Jon", Region: "North America & Caribbean" },
{ Name: "Ruan", Region: "Asia Pacific" }
];
var Regions_Map = [
{ Region: 'Europe', NewRegion: 'EMEA' },
{ Region: 'North America & Caribbean', NewRegion: 'NAC' },
{ Region: 'Asia Pacific', NewRegion: 'APAC' }
];


var result = [];
Master_Array.forEach(function(data){
  var temp = Regions_Map.filter(function(map){
    if(map.Region === data.Region){
      return map;
    }
  });
  if(temp){
  result.push({
        Name : data.Name,
        NewRegion: temp[0].NewRegion
      });
  }
});

console.log(result);
```